# godaddy - htaccess condition not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite working on localhost, but not in godaddy shared host.

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/WebShop/View/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WebShop/View/public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is with the RewriteCond part. It cannot find the exsiting files in the subfolder. I tried with absolute path, relative path, rewritebase everything, but neither of them worked. Godaddy doesn't grant access to the rewritelog... Any idea how to solve this problem?

**Edit:**

The htaccess is in a subfolder, and in the document root is a htaccess which splits the request by domain into subfolders:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And the real problem is, that the %{REQUEST_URI} in the htaccess of the subfolder contains the name of the subfolder too :S

**Edit2:**

Ok I have a partial solution:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/WebShop/View/public/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php?file=%2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA,L]
```

This prints the file name if exists, but it's kind of joke, cause if I change the second rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ x.php [QSA,L]
```

Then everything goes to the x.php. I'm wondering why mod rewrite never recognize the L flag?

*(go drink a beer)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's maybe because of some sort of strange directory settings, but if you redirect to a subDirectory on a godaddy server, you have to create there an empty .htaccess file with RewriteEngine On, otherwise it won't work.**

The preceding code in the edit2 section works well, but not on a godaddy server... Here is the file access version of it:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/WebShop/View/public/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WebShop/View/public/%2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA,L]
```

And I placed an empty .htaccess file with RewriteEngine On in the "WebShop/View/public" directory, that fixed the L flag problem.